# Problema con trigger y secuencia

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, trigger

tengo un problema que lo entiendo a nivel lógico, pero no encuentro la forma de forma de solucionarlo, ¿podrían ayudarme?
Tengo 1 tabla '**empresa_sucursal**', a la cual cuando realizo un INSERT, se activa un trigger before insert con el siguiente código:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auditoria.trigg_bfr_func_validar_id_empresa() RETURNS trigger AS $START$
DECLARE 
    sequence_name TEXT;
    query_create TEXT;
    query_alter TEXT;
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'S' AND oid::regclass::text = (TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_empresa_id_' || NEW.id_empresa)) THEN
        sequence_name := TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_empresa_id_' || NEW.id_empresa;
        query_create := 'CREATE SEQUENCE ' || sequence_name;
        EXECUTE query_create;
        query_alter := 'ALTER TABLE ' || TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || TG_TABLE_NAME || ' ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval(' || sequence_name || ')';
        EXECUTE query_alter;
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$START$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

El problema viene que cuando realizo un INSERT a la tabla nombrada, manda el siguiente error:

```
ERROR:  no se puede hacer ALTER TABLE en «empresa_sucursal» porque está siendo usada por consultas activas en esta sesión
CONTEXT:  sentencia SQL: «ALTER TABLE entidades.empresa_sucursal ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval(entidades.empresa_sucursal_empresa_id_1)» 
función PL/pgSQL auditoria.trigg_func_validar_id_empresa() en la línea 12 en EXECUTE 
SQL state: 55006
```

La idea del trigger es que crear una secuencia para la tabla de la empresa correspondiente en caso de no existir (para que cada empresa tenga sus id de registros únicos), por favor, quien pueda ayudarme, se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUCIÓN**: El problema era que intentaba hacer un **ALTER TABLE** cuando no era necesario en absoluto, ya que el valor sí o sí lo debo asignar ya sea cuando creo la secuencia o cuando ya exista, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION auditoria.trigg_func_bfr_validar_id_empresa() RETURNS trigger AS $START$
DECLARE 
    sequence_name TEXT;
    query_create TEXT;
BEGIN
    sequence_name := TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_empresa_id_' || NEW.id_empresa;
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM pg_class WHERE relkind = 'S' AND oid::regclass::text = (TG_TABLE_SCHEMA || '.' || TG_TABLE_NAME || '_empresa_id_' || NEW.id_empresa)) THEN
        query_create := 'CREATE SEQUENCE ' || sequence_name;
        EXECUTE query_create;
    END IF;
    NEW.id := (SELECT nextval(sequence_name));
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$START$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```